# Inflating layouts on main layout with weight (Dynamically )

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-inflater

I just want to inflate 3 linear layout (problem-inflated layout appears on top)
 1. In top linear 1 
 2. In middle (center) linear 2
 3. and in bottom linear 3

Here is the source ...

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   setContentView(R.layout.blank);

  LayoutInflater li=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

   LinearLayout lean=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlyt);

   Integer[] layouts={R.layout.center1,R.layout.center2,R.layout.center3};

      Intent it1=getIntent();
        boolean chc[]=it1.getBooleanArrayExtra("cselected");

     for(int i=0;i<chc.length;i++)
      {
       if(chc[i])
         {
        //li.inflate(layouts[i],lean);
       Log.d("count in ","count in loop "+i);

       View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(layouts[i], lean, false);
       lean.addView(envy);

      }
     Log.d("layout got","layouts values : "+chc[i]);
    }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I thin you may try another alternative. You can include other 2 layouts in the 1st layout in xml file and then inflate the first xml file. In one xml, you can include another xml in the following way:

```
   <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/titlelayout"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

   <include layout="@layout/title_bar"
       android:id="@+id/titlebar" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i am inflating 3 other layout and adding weight into each layout and problem is that inflated layout shows on top.
while i want to show them 1.on top
2 middle(center)
3.Bottom

Comment: Try adding the layout using LinearLayout and put weight. I have edited my answer for that.